# Why is Spacer() not working in this structure in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have just started learning flutter, and I cannot figure out why a Spacer() will not work in the following structure between the 2 Texts, shouldnt it create space vertically between the 2 Text so that the height of the column is the same as the height of the circular avatar?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestSpacer extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestSpacer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 48,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(Icons.person),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("123"),
                  // Spacer(),
                  Text("456"),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried putting expandables around the column that wraps the text, and still the spacer doesnt work as expected.

Comment: on the row put CrossAxisAlignment.stretch.  That really should be the default, because it's the best starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Spacer` widget fills the available space within the column.

Lets wrap the `column` with a red colored `container` to troubleshoot.

```
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("123"),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text("456"),],),),
```

You will see that the size of the column is small, leaving no space for the `Spacer()` to expand. This is because it has no parent widget that determines the height and width of the Column.

[image]

If we wrap them into an `Expanded` widget, it only expands horizontally.

[image]

So your only solution is to specify the `height` parameter of the `Container` (or `SizedBox`).

Instead of hard coding it, you can make the height match the CircleAvatar in two ways.

1. Label a variable:

   ```
            const double myRadius = 48.0;
            CircleAvatar(
                radius: myRadius,
              ),
            Expanded(child: 
              Container(
                height: myRadius * 2, // *2 to match diameter
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("123"),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text("456"),],),),),
   ```
2. Incase CircleAvatar is not the only widget you are trying to align with, you can use the `LayoutBuilder` widget to get the height constraint of the whole Row.

   ```
     LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints){ 
          return Row(
       children: [
          const CircleAvatar(
            radius: 48,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
         Expanded(child: 
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: const Column(
              children: [
                Text("123"),
                Spacer(),
                Text("456"),],),),),],);}),
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help u,

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Column(
        children: [
          IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 48,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(Icons.person),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("123"),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text("456"),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ))
          
        ],
      ),
    );
```